# Generate JSON based on map keys names

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy and I've a task. I have a Map looks like:

`[sessionCampaignName:renins_KASKO_May23, sessionMedium:Yandex_banners, sessionSource:Media]`
or
`[sessionCampaignName:olv_May23, sessionTerm:greatjob]`

How can i build a JSON based on map keys names + additional json property called `date` like (for example lets take 1st case):

```
[
        {
            "name": "date"
        },
        {
            "name": "sessionCampaignName"
        },
        {
            "name": "sessionMedium"
        },
        {
            "name": "sessionSource"
        }
    ]
```

Tried with:

```
List dimensionsList = convertedMap.collect {dimensionName, dimensionValue ->
        [
            [
                name: 'date'
            ],
            [
                name: dimensionName
            ]
        ]
      }
String jsonDimensions = JsonOutput.toJson(dimensionsList)
```

But didn't reach what I expected to reach. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try as below-

```
def map = [sessionCampaignName: 'renins_KASKO_May23', sessionMedium: 'Yandex_banners', sessionSource: 'Media']

List dimensionsList = [['name': 'date']] + map.keySet().collect { key ->
    ['name': key]
}

/* 
List dimensionsList = map.keySet().collect([[name: 'date']]) { key ->
    [name: key]
}
*/

String jsonDimensions = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(dimensionsList).toPrettyString()
println jsonDimensions
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "date"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionCampaignName"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionMedium"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionSource"
    }
]
```

Comment: `collect` (and many other functions) allow passing the initial data structure to add to.  So this can be golfed to `map.keySet().collect([[name: 'date']]) { key -> [name: key]}`

Comment: Absolutely right! The code can be further simplified by passing the initial data structure directly to the collect